# SQLite Extract JSON Massive and JOIN with him

Tags: json, sqlite, join

I have SQLIte Table **Movies** and column **Writers** with json massive in rows.

Example 1 row.

```
[{"id": "0b60f2f3fd2e12babe918a164dbd8230dd5e3140"}, {"id": "0b60f2f35d7a8e16853803c0e338f0d115d7182e"}, {"id": "0b60f2f3cabb51e1b8cec9bb2cc177d1e3f7f738"}]
```

1. How can I extract this IDs in SQLite?
2. How can I use JOIN with this IDs in SQLite? Because I have Table **Writer** wit IDs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the ids with the function [`json_extract()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex) in conjunction with the function [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach):

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, 
       json_extract(json_each.value, '$.id') writer
FROM Movies m, json_each(Writers)
```

and use them also to join the table `Writers`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, 
       json_extract(json_each.value, '$.id') writer,
       w.name
FROM Movies m, json_each(Writers)
INNER JOIN Writers w ON w.id = json_extract(json_each.value, '$.id')
```

I assume that the table `Movies` has columns `id`, `title` and `Writers` and the table `Writer` has columns `id` and `name`.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=23ea237000a9a780cf75c5f9d7b352ec).

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't work for me. My schema Movies: create table movies
(
    id          text
        primary key,
    genre       text,
    director    text,
    writer      text,
    title       text,
    plot        text,
    ratings     text,
    imdb_rating float,
    writers     text
);   and yes, it is no my base, I must edit this ) Thanks guy

Comment: [2021-05-22 22:49:44] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (malformed JSON)

Comment: @ElonPy as you can see in my demo link my code works fine. It seems you have malformed JSON values in your data.

Comment: yes, you are right. thank you very much. it is work! great code and knowledge for me